# Read, sort and count 20GB CSV file stored in HDFS by using pyspark RDD

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in Spark Hadoop. I got one use case in which I am trying to read, count number of records and sort data in 20GB CSV file. The problem is when I am using these functions its not working. Here is my code please have a look and suggest me the approach to handle the large file with spark RDD.

```
    import findspark
    findspark.init()
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

    APP_NAME = 'My Spark Application'
    file = 0
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("APP_NAME").setMaster("local")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    val_file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:50000/yottaa/transactions.csv")

    val_file.count() ### Its taking 10 mins to execute and produce result.
```

`val_file.count()` ---> It's taking 10 mins time to count rows, How can I increase speed ?. I'm using 16GB RAM laptop and when I am giving `val_file.collect(`) statement it shows me following error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded   at
>   java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)    at
>   java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:331)     at
>   java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:777)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:412)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:389)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:280)     at

Comment: Error? Stacktrace?

Comment: val_file.count() ---> It's taking 10 mins time to count rows, How can I increase speed ?. I'm using 16GB RAM laptop and when I am giving val_file.collect() statement it shows me following error:

Comment: Why are you trying to collect the entire file? Obviously a 20GB file will not fit into 16GB of RAM. You also need to account for the overhead of the Spark JVM. You speed it up with a cluster, but count is a poor method to try because you can count the number of lines in the file without Spark or Hadoop